# Trouble reading reals from unknown length character string in Fortran

Tags: fortran

This is a small portion of the data I am trying to read:

```
 01/06/2009,Tom Sanders,,264,220,73,260
 01/08/2009,Adam Apple,158,,260,,208
 01/13/2009,Lori Freeman,230,288,218,282,234
 01/15/2009,Diane Greenberg,170,,250,321,197
 01/20/2009,Adam Apple,257,,263,256,190
 01/21/2009,Diane Greenberg,201,,160,195,142
 01/27/2009,Tom Sanders,267,,143,140,206
 01/29/2009,Tina Workman,153,,124,155,140
 02/03/2009,Tina Workman,233,,115,,163
 02/03/2009,Adam Apple,266,130,310,,310
```

the numbers between each comma are from a different location
Where two commas would represent missing data and a trailing comma would mean the fifth data point is missing

My goal is to organize the data into a table after calculating the average of each site and person, hence my two dim arrays

I want my output to look something like the following:
(obviously neater formatting but a table nonetheless)

```
              Average Observed TDS (mg/l)
     Name Site 1 Site 2 Site 3 Site 4 Site 5
  ------------------------------------------------------
  Tom Sanders 251.0 172.5 251.7 160.0 229.0  
  Adam Apple 227.0 130.0 277.7 256.0 236.0
  Lori Freeman 194.0 288.0 216.7 279.0 202.7
  Diane Greenberg 185.5 190.0 205.0 258.0 169.5
  Tina Workman 193.0 140.0 119.5 155.0 163.0
```

This is my program so far:

```
program name_finder
implicit none


integer, parameter :: wp = selected_real_kind(15)
real(wp) :: m, tds
real(wp), dimension(20,5) :: avg_site, site_sum
integer, dimension(20) :: nobs
integer, dimension(5) :: x
integer :: ierror, i, nemp, cp, non, ni, n
character(len=40), dimension(20) :: names
character(len=200) :: line, aname
character(len=20) :: output, filename
character(len=3), parameter :: a = "(A)"

do 
    write(*,*) "Enter file to open."
    read(*,*) filename
    open(unit=10,file = filename, status = "old", iostat = ierror) 
    if (ierror==0) exit
end do
 write(*,*) "File, ",trim(filename)," has been opened."


 non = 0
outer: do
     read(10,a, iostat = ierror) line
     if (ierror/=0) exit
     cp = index(line(12:),",") + 11
     aname = line(12:cp-1)

n=0
middle: do
    read(line,'(Tcp,f4.2)') tds
    write(*,*) "tds=", tds
    n=n+1
    if (n>10) exit
    i = 1
    inner: do
        if (i > non) then
            non = non +1
            names(non) = trim(aname)
            !ni = non
            exit
        end if

        if (aname == names(i)) then
            !ni = i
            !cycle outer
            exit inner
        end if
         i = i + 1
       end do inner
     end do middle
 end do outer

 write(*,*)
 write(*,*) "Names:"
 do i = 1,non
      write(*,*) i, names(i)
  end do


  close(10)
  close(20)
  STOP
  end program name_finder
```

TLDR; I am having trouble reading the data from the file shown at the top of each site after the names.

Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following is helpful. I have omitted any easily assumed declarations or any further data manipulation or writing to another file. The code is used just to read the data line by line.

```
character(150)  :: word         
read(fileunit, '(A)') word         ! read the entire line
comma_ind = index(word,',')        ! find the position of first comma

! Find the position of next comma
data_begin = index(word(comma_ind+1:),',')

! Save the name
thename = word(comma_ind+1:comma_ind+data_begin-1)

! Define next starting point
data_begin = comma_ind+data_begin

! Read the rest of the data
outer: do 
   if (word(data_begin+1:data_begin+1) == ',') then
      ! decide what to do when missing an entry
      data_begin = data_begin + 1
      cycle outer
   else if (word(data_begin+1:data_begin+1) == ' ') then
      ! Missing last entry
      exit outer
   else             
      ! Use it to find the length of current entry
      st_ind = index(word(data_begin+1:),',')

      if (st_ind == 0) then 
          ! You reached the last entry, read it and exit
          read(word(data_begin+1:), *) realData
          exit outer
      else
         ! Read current entry
         read(word(data_begin+1: data_begin+st_ind-1),*) realData
      end if
      ! Update starting point
      data_begin = data_begin + st_ind

   end if
end do outer
```

There could be a more elegant way to do it but I cannot think of any at the moment.